# What is the name of the metallic part in this image? (some sort of a brace for vertically connecting wooden blocks around the corner?)

Tags: wood, furniture

What do you call the metallic part in the image below? Looks like a type of brace for vertically connecting parts around the corner. I'm looking to buy parts like this for a DIY project.

[image: diy desk brace]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Big Blue Store" calls it a [Double 90-degree angle.](https://www.lowes.com/pd/USP-Triple-Zinc-Double-90-Degree-Angle/1000184011)
[image]